# difficulties while updating multiple item value in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, arrays, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, foreach

I am new with vb.net and asp.net. I am trying to create a form that will update values in the database.

```
<input type="hidden" id="applicationid" value="<%= Request.QueryString("a")%>" />
```

I have written the above code in the asp.net file.

The value of "a" can be single or multiple values(depending on how many items has been selected in previous page). For an example a=19074,19070,19069 .  these values are item ids.

I have selected 3 items whose ids are 19074,19070,19069.

I have created a code file which can update value if single item is selected. But if there is multiple value item selected then its joints every id together. Like for above example (if 3 items selected ) it becomes 190741907019069

My understanding is this can be done with the help of foreach loop in VacancyApplication property.  Can you please help me with the code.

The code for updating the single value is provided below.

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports NLog

Partial Class E4_Jobs_Details_Application_update_status
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Private _logger As Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()
Private _application As VacancyApplication
Private _vacancy As Vacancy

Public Property VacancyApplication() As VacancyApplication
    Get
        If _application Is Nothing Then
            _application = New VacancyApplication(CInt(Request("a")))
        End If
        Return _application
    End Get
    Set(value As VacancyApplication)
        _application = value
    End Set
End Property


Protected Sub comNewStatus_Init(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles comNewStatus.Init
    If Not IsNothing(Request("n")) Then comNewStatus.Value = Request("n")
End Sub

Protected Sub btnUpdate_ServerClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.ServerClick


            VacancyApplication.Save()
            VacancyApplication.UpdateStatus(CInt(comNewStatus.Value), True, False)

        Response.Redirect("details.aspx?i=" & VacancyApplication.ID & "&c=" & VacancyApplication.StatusID)
End Sub

End Class
```

The vacancy application is a class. The code for this class is written below

```
Public Class VacancyApplication

#Region " Local variables and constants "

Private _id As Integer
Private _vacancyid As Integer
Private _statusid As Integer
Private _status As String
Private _candidatestatus As String
Private _candidateid As Integer

#End Region

#Region " Intialize "

Private Sub Clear()
    _id = 0
    _vacancyid = 0
    _statusid = 0
    _status = String.Empty
    _candidatestatus = ""
    _candidateid = 0
End Sub

Public Sub New(Optional ByVal ID As Integer = 0)
    Clear()
    If ID <> 0 Then Load(ID)
End Sub

#End Region

#Region " Properties - Get and Set "

Public ReadOnly Property ID() As Integer
    Get
        Return _id
    End Get
End Property

Public Property VacancyID() As Integer
    Get
        Return _vacancyid
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _vacancyid = value
    End Set
End Property

''etc
''
#End Region

#Region " Code - Load, Save and Delete "


Private Sub Load(ByVal ID As Integer)

  ''Code for Loading the application

End Sub

Public Sub Save()

  ' 'code for Saving the application, and update the applicationid of referrals and introductions

End Sub

Public Sub Delete()

    ''Delete the application, and update the applicationid of referrals and introductions

End Sub

Public Function UpdateStatus(ByVal StatusID As Integer, Optional ByVal bRequireSendEmail As Boolean = True, Optional ByVal bIsMicrosite As Boolean = False) As Boolean

     ''Code for updating application status 

End Function

#End Region
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to support multiple VacancyApplications.  Then, if there's only 1, it's the same as dealing with 20.

```
Partial Class E4_Jobs_Details_Application_update_status
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private _logger As Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()
    Private _applications As New List(Of VacancyApplication)
    Private _vacancy As Vacancy

    Public Property VacancyApplications As List(Of VacancyApplication)
        Get
            If _applications.Count = 0 Then
                Dim vIDs As New List(Of Integer)
                If Request("a").ToString.Contains(","c) Then
                    Dim vIDStrings = Request("a").ToString.Split(","c)
                    For Each vID in vIDStrings
                        vIDs.Add(CInt(vID))
                    Next
                Else
                    vIDs.Add(CInt(Request("a"))
                End If
                For Each vID in vIDs
                    _applications.Add(New VacancyApplication(vID))
                Next
            End If
            Return _applications
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of VacancyApplication))
            _applications = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

... and so on.  I hope you realise that this changes your `_application` variable to a list, rather than a single object, so please modify the rest of your code accordingly.

(And before I get flamed, I've kept it simple with the CInt/loops - I know there are more complicated but shorter ways of doing it!!)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Grim. you saved my day

To add more detail and to finish the query i am providing the updated lines of code which will go under btnUpdate_ServerClick

```
Protected Sub btnUpdate_ServerClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.ServerClick


    For Each VacancyApplication In VacancyApplications
        VacancyApplication.Save()
        VacancyApplication.UpdateStatus(CInt(comNewStatus.Value), True, False)
    Next



    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "CloseWindowScript", "window.close();", True)

End Sub
```